# tkinter canvas over frame

Tags: canvas, listbox, tkinter

I created a drag and drop program that works fine with one small aesthetic issue. It works by selecting an item in a listbox, converting that to a canvas.create_text, and then dropping that onto the canvas. The only issue is that the create_text is under the listbox, and I was wondering how to make it appear on top of the listbox. I've tried changing the order of initialization, and looked at raise/lower, but I've seen no change.

```
def body(self, master):
    self.list = Listbox(master, width=26, height=10)
    self.list.grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.canvas = Canvas(master, width=350, height=500)
    self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    for j in self.items:
        self.list.insert(END, j)
    self.list.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.onPress)
    self.list.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.onRelease)
    self.list.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.onMotion)

def onPress(self, event):
    '''Being drag of an object'''
    # record the item and its location
    w = event.widget
    index = w.nearest(event.y)
    name = self.list.get(index)
    t = self.canvas.create_text(event.x+350, event.y+90, text=name.replace(' ', '\n'),justify=CENTER, tags='sweden')
    self.dragData["item"] = t
    self.dragData["x"] = event.x
    self.dragData["y"] = event.y
    self.list.delete(index)

def onMotion(self, event):
    '''Handle dragging of an object'''
    # compute how much this object has moved
    deltaX = event.x - self.dragData["x"]
    deltaY = event.y - self.dragData["y"]
    # move the object the appropriate amount
    self.canvas.move(self.dragData["item"], deltaX, deltaY)
    # record the new position
    self.dragData["x"] = event.x
    self.dragData["y"] = event.y

def onRelease(self, event):
    '''End drag of an object'''
    # reset the drag information
    wx, wy = self.canvas.winfo_rootx(), self.canvas.winfo_rooty()
    x,y = self.winfo_pointerxy()
    cx = self.canvas.canvasx(x-wx)
    cy = self.canvas.canvasy(y-wy)
    #Rest of the release code
```

Comment: I don't understand what "the create_text is under the listbox" means. How can it be under the listbox when the listbox and canvas are in two separate parts of the window that don't overlap?

Comment: When I click on an item in the listbox, a create_text is created where the mouse is (in the listbox), but the listbox is on top of it. I'm trying to set it up so that when the create_text is created, it shows up on top of the listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot create text on a canvas but have it appear above some other window. Typically, for a drag and drop operation you will need to create a toplevel window with the overrideredirect flag set to act as the proxy of the object being dragged.